# Окно называется не так

Tags: python, классы, tkinter

Код:

```
from tkinter import *

class newWorld():
    windowName="freesby"

    worldEditor = Tk()

    worldEditor.title(windowName)
    worldEditor.mainloop()

world=newWorld()
world.windowName="opus"
```

Резельтат:
Окно называется `"freesby"`, хотя по-моему оно должно называться `"opus"`.
Подскажите, что делать!

Answer (score 2):

У вас приложение начинается раньше чем оно прочитает `world.windowName`.

1 вариант

```
from tkinter import *


class NewWorld:
    def __init__(self, title, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        window_name = "freesby"
        world_editor = Tk()
        world_editor.title(title)
        print(window_name)
        world_editor.mainloop()


world = NewWorld("opus")
```

---

2 вариант (но как по мне не очень его использовать)

```
from tkinter import *


class NewWorld:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.window_name = "freesby"

        self.world_editor = Tk()

        self.world_editor.title(self.window_name)


world = NewWorld()
world.world_editor.title('opus')
world.world_editor.mainloop()
```